# How to get 'get' method working in vue 3 modal

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, modal-dialog

I have a table of entries and trying to created a modal to view the details of the entry.
However, the modal is unable to get the info and I believe that it cannot access the method within the modal as the cause, but I am not sure how to resolve this.

my code is as follows.

***entryList.vue***

```
 <div>
     <button class="my-button-style details-button" 
     @click="displayDetailsModal(entries.id)">Details</button>
 </div>
```

```
<div>
    <DetailsModal v-show="showDetailsModal" :detailID="selectedDetailsID" @close-modal="hideDetailsModal" />
</div>

<script>
 import DetailsModal from '../components/DetailsModal.vue'

export default
{

components: { DetailsModal },
name: "entryList",
data()
{
    return {
        selectedDetailsID: null,
        showDetailsModal: false,

        //array to store get values from api
        entryList:[],

    }
},
 methods:{
displayDetailsModal(id)
{
    this.selectedDetailsID = id;
    //set modal visbility to true
    this.showDetailsModal = true
},
hideDetailsModal()
{
    //set modal visbility to false
    this.showDetailsModal = false
},

</script>
```

***DetailsModal.vue***

```
<div class="modal-overlay" @click="$emit('close-modal')">

  <div class="modal" @click.stop>
    {{detailID}}
    <button @Click="getDetail()">Get Details </button>
    <button @Click="$emit('close-modal')">Close </button>
  </div>

  <div class="close" @click="$emit('close-modal')">
    <img class="close-img" src="../assets/close.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
```

```
 <script>

 import axios from "axios"
export default {
props: ["detailID"],
methods: {
//Refresh the page here   
reloadPage() {
  window.location.reload();
},
async getDetail(){
    await axios.get('https://testapi.io/api/something/resource/details/' + $this.detailID).then(() =>{
                 //Perform Success Action
                 this.getData()
             }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
        
   }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a typo error here.

```
$this.detailID
```

It should be

```
this.detailID
```

Also, after you send the HTTP request, you didn't get the response value and assign it to `data` variable to show it in the modal

```
export default {
  data() {
     details: null;
  },
  methods: {
async getDetail(){
    await axios.get('https://testapi.io/api/something/resource/details/' + $this.detailID).then((response) =>{
                 //Perform Success Action
                 this.details = response
                 this.getData()
             }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
        
   }
 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to pull the raw json data, now I just need to figure out how to make it presentable haha

Comment: You are welcome, it depends on the type of the data and the way you want to output it.